# How to update subset of fields using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, insert-update, upsert

I have multiple objects with subset of fields from the table. In some cases I should update only one field. How to do this properly in Entity Framework 6.0? The following code throws error due to database constraints because `AddOrUpdate` tries to replace all fields but `FieldName` with empty values.

```
public static TheField Set(TheField f)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyModel())
    {
            dbContext.MyEntity.AddOrUpdate(new MyEntity()
            {
                ForeignId = f.ForeignId,
                FieldName = f.FieldName,
            });
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return f;
    }
}
```

It would be nice to have an extension

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static void AddOrUpdateSchema<TEntity, TKey>(this IDbSet<TEntity> set, TKey id, string schema, 
        params TEntity[] entities) where TEntity : class
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and then use it

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ForeignId { get; set; }

    [UpdateSchema("Schema")]
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class MyEntityView
{
    public int ForeignId { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public static MyEntityView Set(MyEntityView f)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new MyModel())
        {
            dbContext.MyEntity.AddOrUpdateSchema(f.ForeignId, "Schema", new MyEntity()
            {
                FieldName = f.FieldName,
            });
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return f;
        }
    }
}
```

Or maybe Entity Framework already has functionality for this task?

Comment: Do you mean by updating single (or several but not all) property (properties) only? If so, here's what I'm using: public virtual void UpdateProperty(int id, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> navigationProperty, object propertyValue)
        {
            var entityToUpdate = this.dbSet.Find(id);
            var entry = this.context.Entry(entityToUpdate);
            entry.Property(navigationProperty).CurrentValue = propertyValue;
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            this.context.SaveChanges();
        }

Comment: Yes, in most cases i need to update one field of the table or a predefined subset of properties.

Answer (score 0):

Set `State` property to `EntityState.Modified`

`db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below code works for you:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyModel())
{   
    if (dbContext.MyEntities.Any(e => e.ForeignId == f.ForeignId))
    {
        dbContext.MyEntities.Attach(f);
        dbContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(f, EntityState.Modified);
    }
    else
    {
        dbContext.MyEntities.AddObject(f);
    }

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```